# GPGME : Invalid crypto engine

Tags: c++, gpgme

I am trying to check use gpgme on a C++ project but when I try to access the OpenPGP engine

I have install GnuPG on my computer, and I'm running under windows.

More over the command `gpgconf` and `gpg2` works fine, so GnuGP is well installed

I set gpgme's debug level to 9 and I got an error here's the log :

```
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  gpgme_debug: level=9
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  gpgme_debug: gpgme='D:\CODING\C++\bin\Debug'
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  gpgme_check_version: call: 0=00000000, req_version=(null), VERSION=1.6.0
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  gpgme_check_version_internal: call: 0=00000000, req_version=(null), offset_sig_validity=32
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  gpgme-dinfo: gpgconf='C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\gpgconf.exe'
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_pipe: enter: filedes=0028F680, inherit_idx=1 (GPGME uses it for reading)
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_pipe: leave: read=0x0 (00000150/0x0), write=0x1 (00000164/0x0)
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_spawn: enter: path=0AF93FD0, path=C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\gpgconf.exe
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_spawn: check: path=0AF93FD0, argv[ 0] = C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\gpgconf.exe
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_spawn: check: path=0AF93FD0, argv[ 1] = --list-dirs
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_spawn: check: path=0AF93FD0, tmp_name = C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\gpgme-HBCBJ6
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_spawn: check: path=0AF93FD0, CreateProcess failed: ec=87
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_spawn: error: Input/output error
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_close: enter: fd=00000000
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_close: check: fd=00000000, fd=0 -> handle=00000150 socket=-1 dupfrom=-1
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_close: leave: result=0
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_close: enter: fd=00000001
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_close: check: fd=00000001, fd=1 -> handle=00000164 socket=-1 dupfrom=-1
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_close: leave: result=0
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_pipe: enter: filedes=0028F680, inherit_idx=1 (GPGME uses it for reading)
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_pipe: leave: read=0x0 (00000168/0x0), write=0x1 (00000174/0x0)
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_spawn: enter: path=0AF93FD0, path=C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\gpgconf.exe
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_spawn: check: path=0AF93FD0, argv[ 0] = C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\gpgconf.exe
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_spawn: check: path=0AF93FD0, argv[ 1] = --list-components
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_spawn: check: path=0AF93FD0, tmp_name = C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\gpgme-4Cb3i3
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_spawn: check: path=0AF93FD0, CreateProcess failed: ec=87
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_spawn: error: Input/output error
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_close: enter: fd=00000000
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_close: check: fd=00000000, fd=0 -> handle=00000168 socket=-1 dupfrom=-1
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_close: leave: result=0
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_close: enter: fd=00000001
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_close: check: fd=00000001, fd=1 -> handle=00000174 socket=-1 dupfrom=-1
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_close: leave: result=0
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_pipe: enter: filedes=0028FA5C, inherit_idx=1 (GPGME uses it for reading)
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_pipe: leave: read=0x0 (0000017C/0x0), write=0x1 (00000190/0x0)
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_spawn: enter: path=0AF93FD0, path=C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\gpgconf.exe
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_spawn: check: path=0AF93FD0, argv[ 0] = C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\gpgconf.exe
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_spawn: check: path=0AF93FD0, argv[ 1] = --version
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_spawn: check: path=0AF93FD0, tmp_name = C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\gpgme-DrOuSZ
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_spawn: check: path=0AF93FD0, CreateProcess failed: ec=87
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_spawn: error: Input/output error
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_close: enter: fd=00000000
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_close: check: fd=00000000, fd=0 -> handle=0000017C socket=-1 dupfrom=-1
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_close: leave: result=0
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_close: enter: fd=00000001
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_close: check: fd=00000001, fd=1 -> handle=00000190 socket=-1 dupfrom=-1
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  _gpgme_io_close: leave: result=0
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  engine.c:365: returning error: Invalid crypto engine
GPGME 2015-12-28 19:05:21 <0x2b18>  engine.c:155: returning error: Invalid crypto engine
Invalid crypto engine
```

EDIT : 
Here's the code I ran :

```
#include "gpgme.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void genKey()
{
    gpgme_set_global_flag("debug","9");
    gpgme_check_version(NULL);
    gpg_error_t test = gpgme_engine_check_version(GPGME_PROTOCOL_OpenPGP);
    cout << gpgme_strerror(test) << endl;
    cout << "Engine : " << gpgme_get_dirinfo("gpg-name") << endl;
}
```

Comment: It seems your code is working for me except I didn't include the line with the call to `gpgme_get_dirinfo()` because my implementation does not have that function (not sure why).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED :

I installed gpg4win in a dummy directory, I copied the entire directory in my bin. And I add `gpgme_set_global_flag("disable-gpgconf","1")` and `gpgme_set_global_flag("gpg-name","gpgconf")` **BEFORE** `gpgme_check_version(NULL)`. 
It's working now, thanks.